# Lag when creating a new folder

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, user-folders

Every time I try to create a new folder, there is a several second delay.

Here is a video so you can see:

https://youtu.be/Zay0s_AFcDc

In the video the delay actually isn't as bad as it usually is. I've seen it take 10 seconds for the menu to pop up before.

It never used to do this.

One day I got some nasty malware on my computer, thats when this start occurring.

I (believe) the malware with was removed successfully with Malwarebytes, however this is the only side effect I've noticed that is still occurring.

No solutions I've found online so far have been able to fix it. But the problem also wasn't well described, so I'm hoping the video will help.

I know I can do a clean install of windows, but I'd really rather not with how big of a pain it is. I have so many files/programs on this computer that I don't want to have to reinstall, and reinstalling windows always manages to make me lose at least some of it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: Doesn't look like a duplicate to me

Comment: *"One day I got some nasty malware on my computer, thats when this start occurring."*  Realistically, those problems haven't been completely alleviated yet.  I know that it can be rather time consuming, but the only way that you will truly have peace of mind is if you perform a clean install. We are always glad to help, but yes, it really **is** a duplicate.  The root cause of your problems is the malware.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use Nirsoft's ShellExView, located here: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html

This software can show you anything added to the default context menu, so you can see if extra entries are causing delays, or if something malicious is there (or possibly leftover from when you had malware issues). Under Options, you can filter out any default Microsoft entries. This will drastically shrink the list, which by default is quite large.

Please refrain from deleting any entries in this list until you have verified you do not need them. Instead, use the "disable" feature and see if that helps, and verify there are no adverse effects with the change before doing anything permanent.

I cannot endorse the software specifically, as I have only used it long enough to validate that it functions, but Nirsoft's utilities are usually very good.

Comment: Someone else recommended cleaning the context menu as well. I just wasn't sure how to do it. It seemed promising, but I've used the program above, and disabled all non-microsoft items, restarted, and the problem still persists :/ thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

Your malware may not be fully eradicated.

I would suggest to start by running scans using several well-known anti-virus products.

The next is to verify Windows integrity by running
[sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Last effort before re-installation would be to
[Repair Install Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html),
or you could decide to live with the problem.

Comment: I've tried serveral reputable anti-virus deep scans but it is still happening. Also tried sfc /scannow. Still happening. I don't mind reinstalling. It seems like the easiest out. However, I have so much stuff on this computer that I don't want to lose. And a clean install always says "save my files" or something like that but it never does. I know I will end up having to spend day(s) to get my PC back to where it was. No fun.

Comment: Repair Install keeps your applications and almost all Windows settings. But take backups first.